# How to speed up Pyspark programming when you need to split datasets

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I now have encountered some problems.

- I have a whole bunch of stock tick data csv files. I will need to calculate each stock's seconds' level data.
  I want each stock's data can be processed in 10 seconds, combined to a big file,  finally to output to csv.
  becuase using pandas will be restricted by my laptop's memory, if I want to do in pandas, I will need to do a lot of read_csv/to_csv work. I think this will be time cosuming, so I chose this way:
- (1) I use pyspark to read all of the csv files, generate a big file df.
- (2) I got the stock list from the df. Then do for iterations, every time I pick a stock data's pyspark 
  dataframe, transferred it into pandas dataframe, compute it in pandas. Finally, output this file into local files.
  Now the problem is the program is running in a very low speed, for some stock, it uses 2 mins to do the processing. For some stocks, it uses about 18 mins to do the processing.
  I think the problem is related to the pyspark dataframe data partition. The pyspark stored data in a very remote ways, so it will reorganize data to meet my needs. How can I speed it up?

```
#read data
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('data_processing1').getOrCreate()
sc=spark.sparkContext
df=spark.read.csv('file:///D:/t/*.csv',inferSchema=True,header=True,encoding='GBK')

df_empty=spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(),t_schema)#pre-defined schema
#generate code list
codelist=df.select('stks').distinct().collect()
col_list=['stks','time']
df=df.orderBy(col_list,ascending=True)
from time import strftime, localtime
#For loops
for code in codelist:
    print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
    print(code)
    print(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime()))
    df2=df.filter(df['stks']==code[0]).select('mkt','stks','time','price')
    df2_1=df2.toPandas()
    timelist=df2_1['time'].tolist()
    pricelist=df2_1['price'].tolist()
#Add flag----target computation
    flag_1=[]
    flag_2=[]
    for i in range(len(timelist)):
#        calculate 
        flag_1.append(calc_incre_2(timelist,pricelist,i,30,0.05))
        flag_2.append(calc_incre_2(timelist,pricelist,i,40,0.05))
    df2_1['flag_1']=flag_1
    df2_1['flag_2']=flag_2
    df2_2=sqlContext.createDataFrame(df2_1)
    df_empty=df_empty.union(df2_2)
#sub-function----------------------------
def calc_incre_2(timelist,pricelist,start_pos,secs_spec,incre_spec):
    i=start_pos
    flag=0
#    timelist=df2['时间'].tolist()
#    pricelist=df2['最新'].tolist()
    for t in range(len(timelist)-i):
        if (timelist[i+t]-timelist[i]).seconds>secs_spec:
            incre=(pricelist[i+t]-pricelist[i])/pricelist[i]
            if incre>=incre_spec:
                flag=1
            else:
                flag=0
            break
    return flag
```

I was trying to use pandas_udf, while it still can not work. Must get some empty RDD here or there.

```
#read data
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('data_processing1').getOrCreate()
sc=spark.sparkContext
df=spark.read.csv('file:///D:/t/*.csv',inferSchema=True,header=True,encoding='GBK')
df1=df.select('mkt','stks','time','price')
#Using PandasUDF
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
#create the schema for the resulting dataframe
dfs_schema=StructType([StructField('mkt',StringType(),False),
                       StructField('stks',IntegerType(),False),
                       StructField('time',TimestampType(),False),
                       StructField('price',DoubleType(),False),
                       StructField('flag',IntegerType(),False)])
@pandas_udf(dfs_schema,functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def calc_incre_3(spd):
    timelist=spd['time'].tolist()
    pricelist=spd['price'].tolist()
    flaglist=[]
    for i in range(len(timelist)):
        for t in range(len(timelist)-i):
            if (timelist[i+t]-timelist[i]).seconds>30:
                if (pricelist[i+t]-pricelist[i])/pricelist[i]>=0.05:
                    flaglist.append(1)
                else:
                    flaglist.append(0)
                break
    spd['flag']=flaglist
    return spd
pls_df=df1.groupBy('stks').apply(calc_incre_3)
pls_df.show()
```

I have uploaded raw data files.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gc5j36mik71a3yc/AAAUVfNINegdv9ozQPqJYiZHa?dl=0

Comment: Dont convert to pandas.This is slowing you down. Whatever processing you are doing do it in the spark dataframe else you would not be able to use the distributed nodes and partitioning of spark. When you convert to pandas ,it will bring all the partitions together (which is one reason why you are slow) and then you are back on one node and thus unable to use the spark(s) distributed performance.

Comment: thx........I am new to pyspark, found that pyspark dataframe is not so able as the pandas dataframe, I will try to learn more basic spark rdd skills. Thx.

Comment: This time I worked, to find that the problem is related to my using pandas dataframe.iloc processing, After I changed to use list, the speed is a lot faster. But according to knowledge learnt from u, I can speed up more if I do all the wrangling in spark. Now I still have to use local pandas. But I can not find a way to do the same data process in pyspark. Can you help me with it? Or can you guide me a book related..I can not find pyspark code related to my current work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can share some sample data (masked one if there is data sharing issue), it would be easy to suggest how to approach.

Also, share the following information

- a total number of records your market DF has.
- the distinct record count for market and stocks (this helps to design partition).

Your code has 2 issues. Too many loopings (the nested) and function calls (it is not a best practice in PySpark, so to be avoided as much or you can write Java/Scala function and use it via PySpark that is slightly better performance but brings more complexity when it comes to code maintainability)

The recommended approach

- Use right number of Partition which is not specified
- Use window functions to avoid nested looping.
- Also, understand the shuffle behavior in Spark UI to attack the performance problem.
- Flatten the table rather using a nested loop for computation.

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded some simple files....The total number of records are like 20 millon, Distinct record count for market is 2, for stocks it is 4000. Considering every day, every stock, it may be 40K. Because I just want to do 10 days' data yet.